# Programming with Maple for Numerical Analysis : Relative error

Tags: maple, numerical-analysis

I am working on some Numerical Analysis with Maple as a part of my course and I am not sure where my error is with the code I am using.. If anyone can point out my flaw It would be very much appreciated as I seem to be getting the answer wrong.

***f(x)=sqrt((cosh(x))^2 + 1) - sinh(x).
Find a good approximation to f(4.86) using a 6-digit arithmetic.
Then, Use 20 digit arithmetic to calculate the relative error.
Finally, round it to 6 (significant) digits***

```
f := sqrt(cosh(x)^2+1)-sinh(x);

f1 := evalf[6](f(4.86));
                          f1 := 0.0155

f2 := evalf(f(4.86));
                        f2 := 0.01550004

Digits := 20;
                          Digits := 20
Q4 := abs((f2-f1)/f2);
               Q4 := 0.0000025806385015780604437

Digits := 6;
                          Digits := 6
evalf[6](Q4);
                         0.00000258064
```

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made one syntax transcription mistake, and one Maple programming mistake.

Your first line is

```
f := sqrt(cosh(x)^2+1)-sinh(x);
```

but you subsequently call it like an operator (procedure), eg. `f(4.86)` and obtain a numeric value. Therefore you must have originally used something like this procedure, instead.

```
f := x -> sqrt(cosh(x)^2+1)-sinh(x);
```

So that was likely just a transcription error when posting here.

You have made a programming mistake, in computing

```
f2 := evalf(f(4.86));
```

*before* setting the working-precision environment variable `Digits` to `20`. Thus you have computed `f2` at only the default `Digits=10` working precision. But from the wording of the question it seems that you are being asked to compute `f2` also at 20 digits of working precision.

Your code might be revised as follows:

```
restart;
f := x -> sqrt(cosh(x)^2+1)-sinh(x):

f1 := evalf[6](f(4.86));
                  f1 := 0.0155

Digits := 20:

f2 := evalf(f(4.86));
           f2 := 0.015500036806894590

Q4 := abs((f2-f1)/f2);
       Q4 := 0.0000023746327217512077767

evalf[6](Q4);
                 0.00000237463
```

You have used two different mechanisms for specifying the working precision. You could have also done it (slightly more consistently in methodology) as follows:

```
restart;
f := x -> sqrt(cosh(x)^2+1)-sinh(x):

f1 := evalf[6]( f(4.86) );
                  f1 := 0.0155

f2 := evalf[20](f(4.86));
           f2 := 0.015500036806894590

rel := evalf[20]( abs((f2-f1)/f2) );
       rel := 0.0000023746327217512077767

evalf[6]( rel );
                 0.00000237463
```

There's always the possibility that I have misunderstood the question. What is the desired answer?

Comment: Was `0.00000237463` the expected answer?

Comment: Yes Acer. Thank you for your help with this. really appreciate it!